# Why is parse tree not being displayed?

Tags: java, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree, parse-tree

I have an ANTLR grammar and trying to make a parse tree to display using jFrame in Java. However, the parse tree is not being displayed as it can be seen below.

[image: Parse Tree not displaying correctly]

I do notice that if I remove the call to the visitor line `Object answer = new ExpAnalyserBaseVisitor<>().visit(parser.exp());` then the parse tree is displayed correctly. I am not sure why that is a problem and how to fix it.

[image: Parse Tree displaying correctly]

Here is my code for displaying it:

```
CharStream charStream = CharStreams.fromString(exp);

ExpAnalyserLexer lexer = new ExpAnalyserLexer(charStream);
lexer.removeErrorListeners();

CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

ExpAnalyserParser parser = new ExpAnalyserParser(tokens);
parser.removeErrorListeners();

try {
    Object answer = new ExpAnalyserBaseVisitor<>().visit(parser.exp());
    System.out.println("Postfix Expression: " + answer);
}
catch (EmptyStackException e){
    System.out.println("Invalid expression!");
    return;
}

ParseTree tree = parser.exp();
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Parse Tree");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
TreeViewer treeViewer = new TreeViewer(Arrays.asList(parser.getRuleNames()), tree);
treeViewer.setScale(1.5);
panel.add(treeViewer);
frame.add(panel);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(500, 500);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Is there a better way to display the parse tree? Also can I remove the rule names to display in the parse tree also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `parser.exp()` 2 times without rewinding your input stream. The first call consumes all tokens and the second call doesn't find any input, so it cannot parse anything. You should at least call `tokens.reset()` before the second call to `parse.expr()`. Maybe you also have to reset your char stream and the lexer. Play with them.